# Export Content Type to a Form Like Structure?

Tags: forms, nodes

So, I'm just getting really lazy. I have to make new custom forms for users to input data. The form matches the Content Type exactly(except for somethings being generated server-side). Is there a way to just export a Content Type form into an form function?

If not it seems like something I might have fun developing.

Thanks,
Nate

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [Webform Template](https://drupal.org/project/webform_template). All you have to do is make the Webform the one time, then you can copy the configurations for new forms.